# Does Cmake pass its build arguments (eg flags) to external Cmake projects?

Tags: cmake

I have an external project. I pass to it some `CMAKE_ARGS`. I wonder if all the rest of the arguments that are passed to main project are forwarded to external one?

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder if all the rest of the arguments that are passed to main project are forwarded to external one?

No, arguments are not forwarded automatically to ExternalProject.

Even cross-compile state isn't forwarded to ExternalProject.

Every definition which you need for external project you need to pass manually via `CMAKE_ARGS` or other means.